# Personal access tokens with Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Is there way to create user-specific (aka. personal) access tokens in Keycloak?

So, our goal would be that a user creates one or more personal access tokens (like in GitHub or GitLab) and he/she uses these tokens for authentication.

Any idea how to achieve this using Keycloak?

Answer (score 4):

Keycloak have no short size of personal API key
But you can use full size of JWT.
It is getting Access Token with password grant type.

This is demo

**localhost:8180** – is a host and a port number on which the Keycloak server is running,

**test** – is a Keycloak Realm,

**admin-cli** – one of default client,

**user**: user name

**1234**: password

**password** : grand_type

The Grant Type is a way to exchange a user’s credentials for an access token.

```
$ curl -v -d "client_id=admin-cli" -d "username=user" -d "password=1234" -d "grant_type=password" -X POST "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token" | jq '.access_token'
```

result in terminal

```
"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6Q0hvYVhPX2hqbXFRTnNYOVlacnhkZmpUdk1sbWozUFNkSXpTWUJjMzRFIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2NjAzMzU4ODIsImlhdCI6MTY2MDMzNTU4MiwianRpIjoiYmFkMmFlNjktMWNiYS00NGMyLWEyZDctYzdhOWQ5YjQ4OGI4IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MTgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL3Rlc3QiLCJzdWIiOiIzOTRiNjcwOS0zOGEyLTRhYTAtYTg0OS1mZTRjODFlNDA2MjQiLCJ0eXAiOiJCZWFyZXIiLCJhenAiOiJhZG1pbi1jbGkiLCJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiZGM5YjI1YzEtOTRlMy00MTlhLTliOGQtMjYwZTVkMmY3MzcxIiwiYWNyIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlIjoicHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCIsInNpZCI6ImRjOWIyNWMxLTk0ZTMtNDE5YS05YjhkLTI2MGU1ZDJmNzM3MSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwibmFtZSI6IlRvbSBDdXJpZXMiLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6IlRvbSIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiQ3VyaWVzIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ1c2VyQHRlc3QuY29tIn0.Gnx6WwpsUxQM990H89BBYi_Kiy3BdAQcCYFRknDJ9qpkGAZSYrAAjjEeEBA5ZXKIUzu0O2trly0iWVW1r4Lb5ihiqSva1BaR42v5WWXHL9gpeS-ttsoKP6N1x74msHXssRmjN5vZG_dwXF-gpKhhJmXI0fLW3-_uuH3LZ9Ar-4zNliVLjJGmePtzq74nn7WbwhggiWDQu2_mQFBnf9vJvcxn6jY9TX5oxppn4BNcvXrChAZyDXLt7RW32ud3p1Cs7Jn360Vg6cRo4wq7-Mams8hhnonhDEaakJtcin7gLK6jwFC7f2ND8banDYL3CEsem4HpmxSRX43UBhfyO64Z8A"
```

API call for getting user information with this access_token

```
$ curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo' --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6Q0hvYVhPX2hqbXFRTnNYOVlacnhkZmpUdk1sbWozUFNkSXpTWUJjMzRFIn0.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.KNioWAOTl7S5bYi303ZWkYRnTv4BnH9B7Q-Oe6j5nO5g_QD2RrWhMO1bUXA3uHdj5P3Y9Mk3vWYfsOlacVfYGmuYmGYhTD6LhbCILPf1r4qMBHUnAtPmWBUmLPNy1XQc-PPjVU6I0FzwW4-UoHCmrqgpDvSoarxf3PiUgwaYzPGm6IeAaHw-ndSO0vkhue2j2s8eVfiiH6TExkngq3zc8E1Y0WK3EM_LxcoDbfrRTNROYDqjK6Bi6_jIECjuRRC6E4ies1svMd8XGwS8iYuHB62hX7_rEBT4PmCwddjfE-IO6XoPy970gdWFUZfiRxbz1Orh-6SySVaeEPdskTGb2Q' | jq
```

result in terminal

```
{
  "sub": "394b6709-38a2-4aa0-a849-fe4c81e40624",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "Tom Curies",
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "given_name": "Tom",
  "family_name": "Curies",
  "email": "user@test.com"
}
```

You can get the token end point by curl commend.
It is not necessary the access token.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/.well-known/openid-configuration' | jq
```

It will give a full list of result OIDC Discovery

```
{
  "issuer": "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test",
  "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
>>> deleted here next lines
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! It's indeed a way to go... However, for use cases like authenticating within a CI/CD pipeline I don't like the usage of username/password and an additional auth request.

Comment: If you don't like a password option, the **Client Credentials Grant type** is other choice[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955252/keycloak-token-generation-not-working-unauthorized-credentials/63962513#63962513]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can customize the authentication flow using a custom Keycloak authentication SPI in that propagates passed personal token to the same 3-rd service that returns if the user is authenticated or not (see https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_development/topics/auth-spi.html for details)

Of course, you also need to create some web UI for token creation that will be then stored and verified with this custom SPI.